# Why ping returns a completely unexpected address?

Tags: virtualbox, dns, ping

I have 2 VirtuaBox VM's, one is a Univention Corporate Server that's configured as a domain controller and the other one is a Win 10 Pro 1903 joined to such domain. Both are  running on the same host which is Win 10 home. Now, from Win 10 I ping to UCS IP address and it works well (they are both on same subnet). But if I ping instead to UCS server's name (test.in which is how I named UCS server) I expect it to resolve the address of UCS server. Instead, it returns some weird address like 34.202.122.77.

Win 10 machine has the preferred DNS configured to UCS IP address, which is assigned statically.

I already flushed dns cache on Win 10 but ping keeps returning those odd addresses. Is there maybe something I'm missing to configure on UCS? Perhaps there's a way to clear DNS addresses in UCS? I'm not such a experienced guy regarding networks, I'm using VM's to test some development. Any help will be appreciated.

An additional fact is that it used to work before updating Win 10 to 1903.

Comment: The address comes from DNS. If UCS is the DNS server then that is what it thinks it's IP address is. Check the interfaces on the UCS and see if that is the case.

Comment: I did it, but couldn't find any reference to such IP. As far as I can tell, UCS should return 192.168.100.192, i.e., configured UCS IP address is not even in the same segment as the one returned by DNS. Now, after posting my question I realized pinging test.in from another pc in the same segment (192.168.100.102) returned the same odd address. That pc is not joined to UCS domain so I guess that means it's gateway/dns that's resolving that direction. Maybe there's indeed another domain called like that out there which didn't exist before?

Comment: As a workaround, I did set a fixed DNS mapping in the router, i.e., now router, acting as DNS, resolves always the expected address (192.168.100.192). But it still makes me wonder why it is the router that resolves address instead of preferred DNS server set in IPV4 configuration in Win 10. Btw, thanks for quick response.

Comment: If your chosen domain name already exists in global DNS tables then you need to choose a new domain name.

Answer (score 1):

UCS comes with bind9 as DNS service. So if you named your domain "mydomain.example.org", UCS will consider itself to be the authoritative nameserver for "mydomain.example.org". Check the UCR value for "nameserver1". (see also https://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.4.html#computers:Administration_of_local_system_configuration_with_Univention_Configuration_Registry) It should be the IP address of your UCS system.

If a client (like your Windows 10) asks the UCS system for DNS information inside your own domain (e.g. "what's the IP of serverB.mydomain.example.org?"), UCS can answer that on its own (as long as you stored that information in the DNS configuration, see https://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.4.html#networks:dns)

For anything outside of your domain - e.g. "superuser.com", "univention.com" or even "example.org", UCS needs another DNS server it can ask. This is configured via the UCR variable called "dns/forwarder1". This could be 8.8.8.8 or something your ISP told you etc.

Check also nameserver2, nameserver3 and dns/forwarder2, dns/forwarder3.

FYI: https://ipinfo.io/34.202.122.77 <- that IP address belongs to Amazon. UCS does not use any of those on its own.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Grandjean. Would you please elaborate on "as long as you stored that information in the DNS configuration"? I reviewed documentation link you kindly added, but couldn't figure out how precisely to check that out.